# Write the same nested loop n levels deep

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

If I have 3 lists - 'a', 'b', and 'c', and I want to find every possible combination which consists of one value from each loop, that's easy.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]

def combo_finder(a,b,c):
    result = []
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            for z in c:
                result.append([x,y,z])
    return result
```

Or to write it so it can take a single argument, like this:

```
l = [a,b,c]
def combo_finder(l):
    result = []
    for x in l[0]:
        for y in l[1]:
            for z in l[2]:
                result.append([x,y,z])
    return result
```

But say i need it to accomodate an argument l that contains n number of lists inside?   How can I create nested for loops on demand?  I've tried writing recursively, but I seem to keep running into infinite recusion that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why Reut deleted a valid answer - so I'm re-posting my version to it (using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)):

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
l = [a,b,c]
print [x for x in itertools.product(*l)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need.  I didn't know product could take multiple lists like that.  Not very clear in the docs.  Reut's answer was close, but this one showed how to pass an iterable as a single argument using the * , which was needed in this case.  Thanks alfasin!